# How do I add background color in Android?

Tags: kotlin, layout, composable

I keep getting 'Unresolved reference:Green' when adding color with 'modifier = Modifier.background(color = Color.Green)'.

I have tried to resolve this by Importing 'androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Companion.Green' but the error still persists. Is there another way of adding color to background in Kotlin?

Comment: The only import you need is `androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color`, no Companions

Comment: Thank you @Jorn. Importing using **import.androidx.compose.ui.graphics.color** was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

First import Color using **import.androidx.compose.ui.graphics.color** then replace '**modifier = Modifier.background(color = Color.Green)**' with '**modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Green)**'